# Javascript to delete JSESSIONID cookie not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, session-cookies

I am having weird issue with IE10. IE10 is sending expired JSESSIONID cookie for authentication causing the login filure, So am trying to delete the JSESSIONID cookie as below

```
function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    if(getCookie("JSESSIONID"))
        {
        var c = getCookie("JSESSIONID")
            console.log("JSESSIONID = "+ c)
            document.cookie = c + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }
```

Whenever I reload the page I see `JSESSIONID = A64F97BF3AF662AC56238F2C23D529AA` in the console log 
instead of  `JSESSIONID = A64F97BF3AF662AC56238F2C23D529AA=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;`

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're keeping the old cookie value and adding `=` to the end of it. You should be setting the value to an empty string:

```
document.cookie = 'JSESSIONID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Comment: I changed it to `document.cookie = 'JSESSIONID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';` but still am seeing `JSESSIONID = A64F97BF3AF662AC56238F2C23D529AA`  in the console when I refresh the page

Comment: Search for `[javascript] delete cookie` for other questions that show how to delete cookies.